Zsh 5.8.1 in Visual Studio Code 1.89.1 VSC terminal not working in Linux Mint 21.3
Impossible to use Zsh terminal on my VSC
I already checked this :

how to configure VSCode to use oh-my-zsh in Ubuntu 18.04?
ZSH And VSCode - Default Shells
zsh doesn't work in the vscode built-in terminal
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/1bf8anf/the_zsh_terminal_is_not_recognized_in_vscode_oss/?rdt=40593
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_configuration

Note :

"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/zsh" => in VSC settings.json the key "terminal.integrated.shell.linux" not exist anymore in the new version of VSC

this not working


#!/bin/bash exec /usr/bin/zsh

"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "CustomBashWithZsh": {
            "path": "/bin/bash",
            "args": ["-c", "/home/username/start_zsh.sh"],
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "CustomBashWithZsh"



which zsh => works in my linux mint os terminal but not in the sh or bash terminal on vsc

I tried this too :



"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PATH": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin"
}


Edited 3 June 2024

I tried this without sucess => nothing happens ...


 "zsh": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/zsh",
            "args": ["-l"]
        },



I noticed in the bash in VSC, I tried "cd usr", the bash says "bash: cd: usr: No such file or directory" => maybe, I need to give access to some folder in VSC ?


Why do you want to start a bash shell which then in turn starts a zsh? I don't know VSC, but wouldn't it make sense to use "path": "/usr/bin/zsh" and in case you want a zsh login shell, also add  "args": ["-l"]

@user1934428
Why do you want to start a bash shell which then in turn starts a zsh? => yeah, it's weird but I just tried this solution because I found this idea on the web, but this solution is not working
